# Person age program in pascal

Tags: pascal

I have this task and i can't figure out how to do it. 
I need to find persons age in days, there are given birth and death dates, there's data file:

> ```
> 8   
> Albertas Einšteinas     1879 03 14 1955 04 18         
> Balys Sruoga            1896 02 02 1947 10 16  
> Antanas Vienuolis       1882 04 07 1957 08 17   
> Ernestas Rezerfordas    1871 08 30 1937 10 17   
> Nilsas Boras            1885 10 07 1962 11 18   
> Nežiniukas Pirmasis        8 05 24    8 05 25  
> Nežiniukas Antrasis      888 05 25  888 05 25   
> Nežiniukas Trečiasis       1 01 01  125 01 01
> ```

and there's how result file should look like:

> ```
> 1879 3 14 1955 4 18 27775
> 1896 2 2 1947 10 16 18871
> 1882 4 7 1957 8 17 27507
> 1871 8 30 1937 10 17 24138
> 1885 10 7 1962 11 18 28147
> 8 5 24 8 5 25 1
> 888 5 25 888 5 25 0
> 1 1 1 125 1 1 45260
> ```

Few things to notice: all februarys have 28 days.
My function for calculating age:

```
  function AmziusFunc(Mas : TZmogus) : longint;
    var amzius, max : longint;
  begin
    max := 125 * 365;
    amzius := (Mas.mirY - Mas.gimY) * 365 + (Mas.mirM - Mas.gimM) * 31 +
      (Mas.mirD - Mas.gimD);
    if ( amzius >= max ) then amzius := 0;
    AmziusFunc := amzius;
  end;
```

What should i change there? Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question as it stands. For example, what is a TZmogus?

Comment: so the assumption is there is no leap year?

Comment: Andreas - TZmogus - record = vardas : string[25], gimY, gimM, gimD, mirY, mirM, mirD : integer.
Kasturi -> yes, no leap year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function AmziusFunc(Mas : TZmogus) : longint;
    var amzius, max : longint;
  begin
    max := 125 * 365;
    amzius := (Mas.mirY - Mas.gimY) * 365 + (Mas.mirM - Mas.gimM) * 31 +
      (Mas.mirD - Mas.gimD);
    if ( amzius >= max ) then amzius := 0;
    AmziusFunc := amzius;
  end;
```